# Microsoft SQL Server : select top N of each part number produced on each machine, union, and unpivot

Tags: sql-server, distinct, union

I have two machines that each produce the same part numbers. Each machine has three parameters. Data are stored in a row. I want to select the top N results from each of the part numbers produced on each machine based on descending time (i.e. the latest 5 results of parts 1, 2, 3 and 4 produced on machines 1 and 2), unpivot the results and display them with a new row number for each.  Environment is Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Sample data:

```
id  PartNumber  WorkCenter  UniquePartID    Measurement1    Measurement2 Measurement3 transactionDT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1           1           78              24.2            20.6         24.6         2018-08-10 11:03:34.000
2   1           2           135             24.3            20.7         24.7         2018-08-10 11:03:28.000
3   2           2           45              58.7            49.9         59.6         2018-08-09 11:03:22.000
4   2           2           32              58.6            49.8         59.5         2018-08-09 11:03:16.000
5   3           1           65              42.2            35.9         42.8         2018-08-07 11:03:10.000
6   3           2           96              42.2            35.9         42.8         2018-08-07 11:03:04.000
7   4           1           12             108.2            92          109.8         2018-08-06 11:02:57.000
8   4           2           54             108.4            92.1        110.2         2018-08-06 11:02:50.000
9   1           1           77              24.2            20.6         24.6         2018-08-05 11:02:43.000
10  1           1           76              24.2            20.6         24.6         2018-08-05 11:02:36.000
```

First few rows of desired result:

```
ROWID   PARTNUMBER  TIMESTAMP               WORKCENTER  UniquePartID    PARAMETER   MEASUREMENT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1           2018-08-10 11:03:34.000 1            78       Measurement 1     24.2
2       1           2018-08-10 11:03:34.000 1            78       Measurement 2     20.6
3       1           2018-08-10 11:03:34.000 1            78       Measurement 3     24.6
4       1           2018-08-10 11:03:28.000 2           135       Measurement 1     24.3
5       1           2018-08-05 11:02:43.000 2           135       Measurement 2     20.7
6       1           2018-08-05 11:02:36.000 2           135       Measurement 3     24.7
```

T-SQL statement used:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) ROWID, 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
         PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, 
         CASE 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'WC 1' 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'WC 2' 
         END AS WORKCENTER, 
         UniquePartID, 'Measurement1' AS PARAMETER, 
         measurement1 AS MEASUREMENT
     FROM            
         parts.dbo.data 

     UNION

     SELECT DISTCINT TOP 10 
         PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, 
         CASE 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'WC 1' 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'WC 2'  
         END AS WORKCENTER, 
         UniquePartID, 'Measurement2' AS PARAMETER, 
         measurement2 AS MEASUREMENT
     FROM           
         parts.dbo.data

     UNION

     SELECT DISTCINT TOP 10 
         PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, 
         CASE 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'WC 1' 
            WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'WC 2'  
         END AS WORKCENTER, 
         UniquePartID, 'Measurement3' AS PARAMETER, 
         measurement3 AS MEASUREMENT
     FROM            
         parts.dbo.data) a
ORDER BY  
    TIMESTAMP DESC, PARAMETER ASC
```

Thanks!

******UPDATED t-SQL code

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARTNUMBER, WORKCENTER ORDER BY 
    TIMESTAMP DESC) ROWID, *
FROM (

SELECT PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, CASE 
  WHEN WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'Work Center 1' WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'Work 
    Center 2' END AS WORKCENTER, UniquePartID, 'Measurement1' AS PARAMETER, 
                     Measurement1 AS MEASUREMENT, Measurement1Min AS 
    SPEC_MIN, Measurement1Nominal AS NOMINAL, Measurement1Max AS SPEC_MAX
FROM            parts.dbo.data

UNION ALL

SELECT PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, CASE 
    WHEN WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'Work Center 1' WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'Work 
    Center 2' END AS WORKCENTER, UniquePartID, 'Measurement2' AS PARAMETER, 
                     Measurement2 AS MEASUREMENT, Measurement2Min AS 
    SPEC_MIN, Measurement2Nominal AS NOMINAL, Measurement2Max AS SPEC_MAX
FROM            parts.dbo.data

UNION ALL

SELECT PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, CASE WHEN 
    WorkCenter = 1 THEN 'Work Center 1' WHEN WorkCenter = 2 THEN 'Work 
    Center 2' END AS WORKCENTER, UniquePartID, 'Measurement3' AS PARAMETER, 
                     Measurement3 AS MEASUREMENT, Measurement3Min AS 
    SPEC_MIN, Measurement3Nominal AS NOMINAL, Measurement3Max AS SPEC_MAX
FROM            parts.dbo.data) a
order by TIMESTAMP DESC, PARAMETER ASC
```

Challenge - this returns 3 rows for every record...I want 3 rows for the top N of every partnumber / work center combination.

Comment: Quick note, if you know the rows are distinct use UNION ALL to speed it up.

Comment: When and on what has the `TOP N` to be applied? In the result (without `TOP N`), each timestamp will appear three times.

Comment: Wolfgang Kais - the top N should be applied to each of the part numbers (that each machine produces) and each machine - i.e. the most recent 10 part number 1's produced on machine 1, the most recent 10 part number 1's produced on machine 2, the most recent 10 part number 2's produced on machine 1, the most recent 10 part number 2's produced on machine 2, etc.

Comment: Ok, then you would have to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` like in your *updated* request, but in the subquery, and use a `WHERE` clause in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your statement is that you use `TOP 10` in every part of the `UNION` query without sorting.

I guess that you want something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY transactionDT DESC, MEASUREMENT) ROWID,
  PartNumber AS PARTNUMBER, transactionDT AS TIMESTAMP, WorkCenter AS WORKCENTER,
  UniquePartID, PARAMETER, MEASUREMENT
FROM 
   (SELECT TOP (10) PartNumber, WorkCenter, UniquePartID,
      transactionDT, Measurement1, Measurement2, Measurement3
    FROM parts.dbo.data
    ORDER BY transactionDT DESC) AS pvt
UNPIVOT (MEASUREMENT FOR PARAMETER IN (Measurement1, Measurement2, Measurement3)) AS upvt;
```

**UPDATED...**

After the requirements have been extended to 4 instead of 1 column, I can't seem to find a different way to solve this than using the `UNION ALL` approach. As with the `TOP N` in my answer to the original question, the numbering with `ROW_NUMBER()` in my solution to the extended requirements has to be done "early", in this case this means that it has to take place already in each single part of the `UNION` query. The `TOP 10` will be found using a `WHERE` clause in the end:

```
WITH 
  NumberedRecords (ROWID, PARTNUMBER, TIMESTAMP, WORKCENTER, UniquePartID, PARAMETER, MEASUREMENT, SPEC_MIN, NOMINAL, SPEC_MAX) AS (

    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartNumber, WorkCenter ORDER BY transactionDT DESC)
      , PartNumber, transactionDT, 'Work Center ' + CAST(WorkCenter AS varchar(10)), UniquePartID
      , 'Measurement 1', Measurement1, Measurement1Min, Measurement1Nominal, Measurement1Max
    FROM parts.dbo.data

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartNumber, WorkCenter ORDER BY transactionDT DESC)
      , PartNumber, transactionDT, 'Work Center ' + CAST(WorkCenter AS varchar(10)), UniquePartID
      , 'Measurement 2', Measurement2, Measurement2Min, Measurement2Nominal, Measurement2Max
    FROM parts.dbo.data

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartNumber, WorkCenter ORDER BY transactionDT DESC)
      , PartNumber, transactionDT, 'Work Center ' + CAST(WorkCenter AS varchar(10)), UniquePartID
      , 'Measurement 3', Measurement3, Measurement3Min, Measurement3Nominal, Measurement3Max
    FROM parts.dbo.data

  )
SELECT * FROM NumberedRecords WHERE ROWID <= 10;
```

**The simple way:**

Now knowing that it will be a query with `UNION`, there is a simple solution with just a small change to what you already did that will work for both your original and your updated query:

In your `OVER` clause for the `ROW_NUMBER` function in the outer query, add the field `PARAMETER` for partitioning.

And of course, use a `WHERE` clause in the end:

```
WHERE ROWID <= 10
```

Comment: Working through this, I don't believe that I can use UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY because of the columns that I have to pull out for each measurement.  I've put together a T-SQL statement that pulls everything together...I just need to grab the top N rows (by transactionDT descending) for each part number / work center combination.  I've attached the t-SQL statement

Comment: The `UNPIVOT` approach works well when using ONE group of columns like you did in your original question.

Comment: @scootsch You extended the problem, I extended my answer.

Comment: @Wolfgain Kais - thank you!  I (wrongly) thought that I could share the core of my problem and add the details myself later...but the suggestions quickly proved that wouldn't be possible.  Again - thank you!

Comment: Thank you!  Your solution worked nearly perfectly.  I have to add a ROW_NUMBER command to the final select to get a unique ROWID for my resultant table.  I greatly appreciate your help and that of @LukStorms.

Comment: I've upvoted both answers but my lack of reputation prevents them from being shown.  Again - thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much! As I added under "The simple way": If you want to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function in the outer query, add the field `PARAMETER` after `PARTITION BY`, that will have the same effect as numbering the records in each of the three inner queries.